# Spring - SimpleJdbcCall - Unable to locate the corresponding parameter value for '***' within the parameter values provided

Tags: java, spring, procedure, simplejdbccall

I have the code below. Basically I'm trying to retrieve data from procedure to the Spring project.
I got two out parameter which are Struct and Array which makes the process complicated. But for the inOut Array parameter i have **Unable to locate the corresponding parameter value for 'p_process_results' within the parameter values provided: [p_claim_id, p_sf_no, p_user]** this error. I couldn't find what's wrong with the Component class.

This is the code I'm trying to transform to the Spring Project.

```
String statement =  "BEGIN  CUSTOMER.alz_exw_clm_transaction_utils.GET_MX_CLAIMS_INFO(?,?,?,?,?); END;";
        conn = DbUtils.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareCall(statement);
        stmt.setInt(1, claimId);
        stmt.setInt(2, sfNo);
        stmt.setString(3, username);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.STRUCT, ClaimMxStruct.recTypeName);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.ARRAY, ProcessResultType.tblTypeName);
        stmt.execute();
```

Spring Repository

```
public class ClaimMxRepository extends NamedParameterFactory{

@Qualifier("getClaimMxInfo")
private final SimpleJdbcCall getClaimMxInfo;

public ClaimMx getClaimMx(ClaimMxReq request) throws SQLException {
    
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("p_claim_id", request.claimId);
    params.put("p_sf_no", request.sfNo);
    params.put("p_user", request.username);
    
    Map<String, Object> result = getClaimMxInfo.execute(params);
    //ClaimMxStruct struct = (ClaimMxStruct) result.get("p_claim_mx_rec");
    //Array arr = (Array) result.get("p_process_results");

    
    return null;
}
```

}

Component

```
    @Bean(name = "getClaimMxInfo")
public SimpleJdbcCall getClaimMxInfo() {
    return simpleJdbcCallService.simpleJdbcCallWithCustomerSchema("ALZ_EXW_CLM_TRANSACTION_UTILS", "GET_MX_CLAIMS_INFO")
            .declareParameters(
                    sqlParameterWithNumeric("p_claim_id"),
                    sqlParameterWithNumeric("p_sf_no"),
                    sqlParameterWithVarChar("p_user"),
                    new SqlOutParameter("p_claim_mx_rec", STRUCT, "CUSTOMER.CLAIM_MX_REC", new SqlReturnStruct(ClaimMxStruct.class)),
                    new SqlInOutParameter("p_process_results", ARRAY,"CUSTOMER.PROCESS_RESULT_TABLE", new SqlReturnArray()));
            
}
```

Procedure

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CUSTOMER."ALZ_EXW_CLM_TRANSACTION_UTILS"
IS

   PROCEDURE get_mx_claims_info (
      p_claim_id                   NUMBER,
      p_sf_no                      NUMBER,
      p_user                       VARCHAR2,
      p_claim_mx_rec      OUT      customer.claim_mx_rec,
      p_process_results   IN OUT   customer.process_result_table
   )
   IS
```

Answer (score 0):

p_process_results is not included in your query. Also add it to your model too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).